# How to append the results of an R Script to the same output file after running the same script several times

Tags: r

I am collecting tweets from the twitter search API. I am storing these tweets in a CSV file. I have automated the R Script to run several times daily using Task scheduler on windows. So every time the script runs it generates a CSV file which replaces the previous one. So what I want is to append the tweets in every CSV file generated into a single file. I dont want to generate a new file everytime and then merge them together later but to keep adding the results to the file which was generated first time the script was run. So is there a way to do this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `write.csv(..., append=T)`?

Comment: Tried it but it gives a warning saying attempt to set append ignored.

Comment: My bad – `write.table(..., append=T)` as per `?write.table`: "These wrappers are deliberately inflexible: they are designed to ensure that the correct conventions are used to write a valid file. Attempts to change `append`, `col.names`, `sep`, `dec` or `qmethod` are ignored, with a warning."

Comment: Ok it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `write.table` with `append=T`:

```
write.table(newdata, file="twitterdata.csv", append=T, sep = ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make a 'working' data.frame for each harvest, rbind.data.frame it to a 'master results' data.frame, and then save the 'master results'.  Not complicated but it works.